# Search whole sheet with find returns empty values

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement, find

I am trying to search a whole sheet with the below code. Essentially workbook A has a column of values (codes) in (column A) and searches that code in workbook B. Workbook B has codes with their descriptions, those descriptions are to the right of the code, but the distance is variable (which is why it's xlToRight, rather than offset).

It works when I put a breakpoint and run the code manually, however, running the code turns up empty searches. I have tried setting the search value as

```
FindString = MainSht.Range("A" & x).Value
```

as well as

```
FindString = MainSht.Range("A" & x).Text
```

but both turn up empty searches (or rather they return an "N/a" which is wrong cause I find the values when searching manually).

I need to be able to search the whole worksheet so I am setting the range as **.Cells**.

```
Sub One_Find()

Dim Compld As Range
Dim FindString As String
Dim x, NumRows As Integer
Dim MainSht, SearchSht As Worksheet
Dim MainBk, SearchBk As Workbook

Set MainBk = ThisWorkbook
Set SearchBk = ActiveWorkbook


Set MainSht = MainBk.Sheets("Curr des")
Set SearchSht = SearchBk.Sheets("Current")

Set SearchRng = SearchSht.UsedRange '.Cells

NumRows = MainSht.Cells(MainSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


For x = 2 To NumRows


FindString = MainSht.Range("A" & x).Text


With SearchRng
Set Compld = .Find(what:=FindString, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
  If Not Compld Is Nothing Then
    MainSht.Range("B" & x).Value = Compld.End(xlToRight).Value
  Else
    MainSht.Range("B" & x).Value = "N/a"
  End If
End With
Next


End Sub
```

Let me know if you need more information!

Comment: What is the aim of `Compld.End(xlToRight).Value` ?

Comment: It returns the first value to the right of the searched text. Essentially workbook A has a column of values (codes) in (column A) and searches that code in workbook B. Workbook B has codes with their descriptions, those descriptions are to the right of the code, but the distance is variable (which is why it's xlToRight, rather than offset)

Comment: `SearchSht.Cells` is a mighty big range to search. Might you perhaps compromise on `SearchSht.UsedRange.Cells`? Some of the `Find` parameters are remembered from the last search, even if it was manual. Call the function with all its arguments. What's `FindString`? `What:=` is a Variant by nature (look at the MSDN page for "Find"). Look out for blanks that might be in your worksheet or look for `xlPart`. It's that line of your code that fails. So, only that needs fixing - for now.

Comment: So are you saying that if there are blanks in Workbook B that will cause the code to fail? I completely agree with your     .UsedRange     suggestion and have edited the code to just search that range. Do you mean i need to go to MSDN to understand Find more? Lastly, FindString is a string of characters (no more than 10 char) ranging from numbers to letter.

Comment: I see no problems with your code, so there is something else going on which we don't know about.  If you can post an example workbook which shows the problem that can help (host on ondrive/dropbox/etc and post a link)

Comment: Don't use `ActiveWorkbook!` When you `Set SearchBk = ActiveWorkbook` you set the variable to `ThisWorkbook`. Test this by inserting `Debug.Print SearchBk.Name` just below  `Set SearchBk = ActiveWorkbook`, and step through your code using `F8`, the workbook name will be displayed in the `Immediate` window (*Ctrl+G* will open the Immediate Window). The name will be the name for `ThisWorkbook`. Unless you have a sheet with the name `Current` in `ThisWorkbook`, you should be receiving a `Run-time error #9` popup message, on `Set SearchSht = SearchBk.Sheets("Current")`

Comment: @GMalc - it's perfectly fine to use `ActiveWorkbook` - *as long as that's clear in the code*. It's *implicit* references to ActiveWorkbook which are a problem.  "When you Set SearchBk = ActiveWorkbook you set the variable to ThisWorkbook"  This is not necessarily the case: if I run a macro in WorkbookA while WorkbookB is active then ActiveWorkbook = WorkbookB and  ThisWorkbook = WorkbookA.

Comment: I don't understand as in your code I don't find that you set a variable for workbook A and workbook B ? And isn't `Set MainBk = ThisWorkbook` and `Set SearchBk = ActiveWorkbook` the same ?

Comment: Karma I agree, I will edit the post to make Workbook A and B more clear. Tim, I figured out what was wrong in the code - it looks like variatus was correct, the issue was in the .Find line. However, the code takes a long time to run nonetheless and I wonder if this is the best method to search. I will answer this question but curious if maybe I should do another post to see whether there is a better method to search a worksheet?

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't disagree with you, but the way the OP was using it in his/her code was causing `SearchBk` to be the same workbook as `MainBk`, by assigning `MainBk` to `ThisWorkbook` he is implying that the macro is in `ThisWorkbook` which would set it as the `ActiveWorkbook`, causing an error if `ThisWorkbook` did not have a sheet call `Current`.

Comment: @GMalc - `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook containing the code being run: if that's not the active workbook, then ThisWorkbook != ActiveWorkbook .  There is no fixed relationship between `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: Running Find() in a loop can be slow if you have a lot of data.  Using Match can be faster but depends on looking in a single column...  I would post a new question with some example data and a few more details such as how many rows etc.